# Como obtengo el empleado con mas ventas en los ultimos 30 dias tomando como punto de referencia la fecha actual

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer un procedimiento para crear un dashboard para mi aplicacion. Quiero mostrar el empleado que mas a vendido en los ultimos 30 dias, siempre tomando como referencia la fecha actual (cada vez que se inicie la aplicacion).

Hasta ahora solo tengo este query:

```
select empleado.Nombres, count(ventas.IDVenta) from Tab_ventasdetalle as ventas INNER JOIN Tab_empleados as empleado on ventas.Vendedor=empleado.Identificacion group by empleado.Nombres
```

[image: imagen 1]
[image: imagen2]
Pero este me devuelve solo el nombre del empleado y la cantidad de ventas que ha realizado. Necesito que me devuelva el empleado top, es decir, el que mas ha vendido en los ultimos 30 dias.

No se como pasarle el parametro para que evalue los ultimos 30 dias apartir de la fecha actual.

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregar una condición donde la fecha de venta esté entre hoy menos 30 días `DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())` y hoy `GETDATE()`

```
    select top 1 empleado.Nombres, count(ventas.IDVenta) as totalVenta
    from Tab_ventasdetalle as ventas 
    INNER JOIN Tab_empleados as empleado on ventas.Vendedor=empleado.Identificacion
    WHERE
    ventas.fecha between  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
    group by empleado.Nombres 
    order by totalVenta desc
```

Comment: faltaria que solo le muestre 1 empleado (el que mas vendio), la mejor solucion es top(1) u otra? hace mucho no hago consultas desde sql

Comment: Cierto @RamiroBarone, hacía falta el top 1 y ordenarlo por totalVenta de forma descendente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @RamiroBarone